# What was Shaytaan's duaa?

Tags: hadith

I remember long time ago reading about a duaa shaytaan made for Allah where he was granted sustenance and shelter for his children. Can't find the script, though.

Comment: The du'a of Iblees is mentioned in the qur'an and it doesn't match your description. However Allah granted him to fulfill it.

Comment: Take a look at verse 7:14